# Hitting maximum usage limits in Cloud Shell, service unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, quota

I am receiving this error message in Google Cloud Shell:

```
Service usage limits temporarily exceeded. Try connecting later.
```

What are the applicable usage limits for Cloud Shell?

For background: I have been running quite a few `docker build`s inside Cloud Shell, and will probably run those on a VM instance of my own in the future. But in order to proceed I need renewed access to Cloud Shell for exporting my current files from its local file system. "Later" apparently means "at least several hours".

**UPDATE** I did not find any documentation on this usage limit by Google. In practical terms, it showed up twice after approx. a week of intense use of Google Cloud Shell (esp. for building Docker images) in each case and went away after approx. 2 days of inactivity.

I've now [switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971385/workflow-for-building-pushing-and-testing-docker-images-inside-gke-kubernete) to (`ssh`ing into) a private VM instance instead of Google Cloud Shell. Again in practical terms, a GKE cluster node (as in `gcloud container clusters`) serves best, because a "raw" GCE VM instance does not have docker installed. On a GKE cluster node, `sudo docker build` succeeds but unfortunately and for yet unclear reasons `sudo docker push` fails with `denied: Access denied.` after pushing a few layers.

Comment: has you found solution for that yet?

Comment: Cloud Shell usage limits are certainly mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations) .The documentation also makes reference to a link pointing to an appeal form but the document does not make reference to specific thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

Google offers Container-Optimized OS which is optimized to run Docker containers however this is still in Beta phase. More information about it can be found in this Help Center [article](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/).

However, for the Cloud Shell usage limits, as Carlos mentioned in the comment the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#usage_limits) explains the usage limits but doesn't provide specific threshold and if your session is terminated or cannot be established because you exceeded a service limit, Cloud Shell will display an error with a link to a form that allows you to appeal the limit violation. Click the feedback link and submit the form with more information about the tasks you were performing before your session was terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, opened a ticket with GCP and asked for them to increase my quota to 100 hours. Not sure if the feedback button yields the same results, but you can share feedback for this as well. If this isn't your issue, there'a StackOverflow question for this with other answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38698688/3600709